# Ubuntu doesn't work with Samsung 3840x1080 ultrawide monitor

Tags: 20.04

I have a Samsung C49HG90 Super Ultrawide monitor with a resolution of 3840x1080. However, when I try to install Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) and use it with the monitor, the screen just goes black. The only way I can get it to work is if I set the monitor in Picture-by-Picture mode and set one of the inputs to the Ubuntu screen, making it 1920x1080 resolution and therefore usable. I'm new to Ubuntu, so I'm not sure what to try here. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What video card do you have? Does a Live USB work?

Comment: In order for people to help you I would edit your original question with the output from the following terminal commands: `xrandr` which will show your monitors and supported resolutions and also `sudo lshw -C display` which will show details of your graphics adaptors. Also have you checked the specs of your graphics card to see if it supports outputting 3840x1080?

Comment: I have a GeForce GTX 750 Ti, which outputs in 3840x1080 just fine on Windows 10. And no, I encounter the same issue on a Live USB and even the installer.